# modeling cumulative effect of a winter

Tags: modeling, time-varying-covariate, ecology

I am trying to make a model that predicts the survival rate of wildlife based on the severity of an entire winter. The idea is that colder weather in combination with lots of snow has a negative effect (the colder it is the longer the snow lasts). It might be cold winter with lots of snow, but if the cold and snow did not occur in the same month it would have less of an effect. In order to preserve the interaction of snow and temp, we want to use monthly data, but our survival will always be for the entire winter. It doesn't really matter which month the bad weather occurs in so I am hesitant to use month as a variable.

Is there some technique that I can use where it preserves the interaction of snow and temp each month but uses the cumulative effect of all months in a winter to predict survival?

example of what the data looks like:

```
Year1 survival = 0.9
month      temp     snow
 m1         -5       20
 m2        -15       20
 m3        -20      100
 m4          2      100

Year2 survival = 0.7
month     temp     snow
 m1        -5       20
 m2       -18      110
 m3       -20      100
 m4       -11       20
```

Temp was the average temperature for the month, and snow was the sum of all snow in a month.  I'm not sure where the comment about order statistics is going but if it makes a difference daily data is available.

Comment: Is the monthly temperature value some sort of average or an order statistic?

Comment: it is the average temp, but see the edit...

Comment: I might enter all the winter month temps and snow falls as separate explanatory variables in a generalized linear model with a logit link and the binomial family since the outcome is a proportion in each year.

Comment: An alternative to GLM would be to logistically transform your outcome variable and use a standard time series model.

Comment: In a lot of the survival data, only the whole winter survival rate is known. So in my data example above, if I would put 0.9 as the outcome of each of the four months in year1, it seems like this would confuse the model... Here is another example that I think better illustrates why I find this challanging: if there was really good weather for 3 months, then the storm of the century his in the 4th month making a very bad survival outcome for that winter. The model would try to fit the 3 good months to the same bad survival outcome for that year.

Comment: I am suggesting that you regress *annual* data on temp and and snow for each of the four months *in that year*, and perhaps their interactions. This will also allow you to test your theory that effects of weather in month 1 is the same as in month 2.